# How do I HTTP GET a .js file and extract 'exports' variables?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am writing a site in Laravel to complement a game written in Node. It pulls information directly from the game's .js files stored on GitHub and the plan is to use Vue to generate some nice HTML to display the data.

The .js files are of the form:

```
'use strict'

let x = {...};

exports.x = x;
```

I can import the files using a PHP request (simply using 'file') and pass them to JS with either jQuery.getScript or axios.get (so far). However, I am having real trouble coming up with a way to extract the 'x' values here under exports. If I were writing a JS app in node, I would simply do the following:

```
var xFile = require('xFile');

var x = xFile.x;
```

However, I can't figure out how to do that here as both GET methods return a string, not a JS file. JSON.parse() doesn't work, and I would like to come up with a solution that doesn't just replace the non-JSON text as I would need a reusable solution for other files. I don't suppose anybody has any ideas?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you using ES6 in your laraval project?

Comment: I don't know - how would I find out? Thanks.

Comment: Are you transpiling your code. Do you have a babaelrc, webpack, gulp plugin, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out! It's a little janky, but you can run a node file in PHP with the `exec` command. I just wrote a node file to import the file and return the useful data. This probably isn't an optimal solution, but it works for me since I'm much more confident with JS than with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below.

you could create the script tag dynamically and attach the script in the body and add your javascript code using `innerHTML`.

You call this script in your ajax response code.

```js
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = 'alert("Hi")';
 document.querySelector('body').appendChild(script);
```